# Switch statement using algorithmic environment

Tags: algorithmic

How to use `Switch` statement in `algorithmic` environment. I tried the following sample code but the errors are: unrecognized command (`algorithmicswitch`, `algorithmiccase`, `\Switch`, `\EndSwitch`, `\Case`, etc.).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
% New definitions
\algnewcommand\algorithmicswitch{\textbf{switch}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmiccase{\textbf{case}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicassert{\texttt{assert}}
\algnewcommand\Assert[1]{\State \algorithmicassert(#1)}%
% New "environments"
\algdef{SE}[SWITCH]{Switch}{EndSwitch}[1]{\algorithmicswitch\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicswitch}%
\algdef{SE}[CASE]{Case}{EndCase}[1]{\algorithmiccase\ #1}{\algorithmicend\     \algorithmiccase}%
\algtext*{EndSwitch}%
\algtext*{EndCase}%
 \begin{figure}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \Switch{$s$}
 \Case{$a$}
 \State hello1
  \State hello1
\EndCase
\Case{$b$}
\State hello2
  \State hello2
\EndCase
\EndSwitch
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Pseudocode}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version? Your code works for me.